# Calculate a DFT of a simple finite signal {+1, −1, +1, . . .})

Tags: dft

Hey i was wondering whether approach presented in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mkGsMWi_j4Q) (6:10) is a good approach to solve this task. Cause it seems kinda tricky and i was wondering whether it can be done faster.

Comment: Hi ! What's the length of that $\pm 1$ sequence ? And what length DFT do you want to compute ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computing the DFT sum

$$X[k]=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x[n]e^{-j2\pi nk/N},\qquad k=0,1,\ldots,N-1\tag{1}$$

directly can be tedious. A computer would generally use a [Fast Fourier Transform (FFT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) algorithm.

For the special class of exponential signals

$$x[n]=a^n,\qquad n=0,1,\ldots,N-1\tag{2}$$

$-$ and your example is a special case of Eq. $(2)$ $-$ you can find a closed-form expression for $X[k]$ by using the [geometric sum formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula). (Just be careful with those values of $k$ for which the denominator of that formula would become zero.)